# "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SBJsonParser", referenced from: objc-class-ref in YFStockSymbolSearch.o

Tags: ios, objective-c, linker-errors

**Hi everybody.I has a problem when I building a xcode project contains BSYahooFinance classes.
The details of this problem:**

> Ld
>   /Users/yxu/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/exchange-avxwiknpprmcnlhgjynxlmbwglpm/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/exchange.app/exchange
>   normal i386
>       cd /Users/yxu/Documents/project/exchange
>       setenv IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 6.1
>       setenv PATH 
> "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
>       /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang
>   -arch i386 -isysroot 
> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.1.sdk
>   -L/Users/yxu/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/exchange-avxwiknpprmcnlhgjynxlmbwglpm/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator
>   -F/Users/yxu/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/exchange-avxwiknpprmcnlhgjynxlmbwglpm/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator
>   -filelist /Users/yxu/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/exchange-avxwiknpprmcnlhgjynxlmbwglpm/Build/Intermediates/exchange.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/exchange.build/Objects-normal/i386/exchange.LinkFileList
>   -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -Xlinker -no_implicit_dylibs -mios-simulator-version-min=6.1 -framework CoreData -framework CoreFoundation -lxml2 -lz -framework MobileCoreServices -framework SystemConfiguration -framework CFNetwork
>   -framework UIKit -framework Foundation -framework CoreGraphics -o /Users/yxu/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/exchange-avxwiknpprmcnlhgjynxlmbwglpm/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/exchange.app/exchange
>
> Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
>   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SBJsonParser", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in YFStockSymbolSearch.o
>         objc-class-ref in YFStockDetailsLoader.o
>  ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
>  clang: error: linker command failed
>   with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

**I have found many answers like "find the .m files are in your project" or "add the framworks needed" from google.I tried them all, but still couldn't solve this problem. Dose anybody of you can give me some suggestions or seen this problem before?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to link in a fat binary with the i386 object files for SBJsonParser into your target.

Comment: great! If an answer solved the problem you should accept it on Stack Overflow.